# General formula of $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a_n)^{b_n}$ where $b_n \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function, exponentiation

> What is the general formula of $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a_n)^{b_n} \quad \text{where} \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty?$$

For example we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n = e$$

Now I want a general formula for $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a_n)^{b_n}$. I know if $a_n \to A \neq 0$ then the answer is infinity. But I am not sure about what will happen when $a_n \to 0$. Maybe the answer is $e^c$ where $c = \lim _{n \to \infty} b_n a_n$. But even if this is the answer, I want the proof.

It seems it must be a famous problem but unfortunately, I couldn't find the answer in math.SE. If an answer exists with proof, please post its link in the comments and I will delete my question.

Comment: I don't think there's a general formula...

Comment: @yanko maybe there is a formula for at least simple sequences like $p(n) / q(n)$ where $p(n)$ and $q(n)$ are polynomials. for example $(1 - n/(n^2 +2n +10))^n$

Comment: A proof for the fact that it converges to $e^c$ if $b_na_n\rightarrow c$ is what you look for?

Comment: @Yanko yes. If it is really convergent to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c_n := a_n b_n$ and assume that $0\lt a_n\rightarrow 0$, $b_n\rightarrow \infty$. Then define:
$$
A_n:={\left(1+a_n\right)^{b_n}}=\left({\left(1+a_n\right)^{a_n^{-1}}}\right)^{c_n}
$$
From this we can clearly observe that the limit of $A_n$ indeed depends on $c_n$. In particular, if $c_n \rightarrow B$, for some $B$, then $A_n\rightarrow e^{B}$. Otherwise, if $c_n$ is divergent, then so is $A_n$.

Comment: (+1) and this is an overkill. It basically gives kind of a formula which depends on $c_n$ only. I mean, informally you prove that  that $A_n\rightarrow e^{\lim_n c_n}$.

Comment: Very good. It is a simple and clever proof for this problem which is also easy to remember when somebody asks for a proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If the limit does exist, we take logs of both sides, getting
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a_n)^{b_n}
 &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\left(b_n \ln (1+a_n)\right) \\
 &= \exp \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n \ln (1+a_n)\right) \\
 &= \exp \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+a_n)}{1/b_n}\right)
\end{split}
$$
So if $a_n \to 0$, we end up with a $0/0$ form, and L'Hospital's rule applies, and the rest depends on the particular dependencies of $a_n$ and $b_n$ on $n$.

**UPDATE courtesy of Andrew in comments below**

Since $a_n \to 0$, we can use L'Hospital's rule to see that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+a_n)}{a_n}
 = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\ln (1+u)}{u}
 = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{1}{1+u}
 = 1.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+a_n)}{1/b_n}
 &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+a_n)}{a_n} [a_n b_n] \\ 
 &= \left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+a_n)}{a_n}\right]
    \left[\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n \right] \\
 &= \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n b_n)
\end{split}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a_n)^{b_n}
 = \exp \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+a_n)}{1/b_n} \right)
 = \exp \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n b_n)\right)
$$

As the example mentioned in the question, if $a_n=1/n, b_n=n$ so $a_n \cdot b_n = 1$, we would get from our result $(1+1/n)^n \to e^1 = e$, as expected.

Comment: Would you be able to simplify this slightly by noting that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+a_n)}{a_n}=\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+u)}{u}=1$? You can then use limit laws to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+a_n)}{1/b_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+a_n)}{a_n} \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n$.

Comment: Looks really interesting, will add into my answer, Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n,a_n$ such that $\lim_n a_nb_n=c$. Moreover assume that $a_n\rightarrow 0$.

Then we have

$$(1+a_n)^{b_n} = (1+a_n)^{\frac{c}{a_n}}  \cdot (1+a_n)^{b_n-\frac{c}{a_n}}$$

We deal with each term alone:

First, since $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\rightarrow e$ we have that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{cn}\rightarrow e^c$. As $a_n\rightarrow 0$ we can substitute $a_n$ with $\frac{1}{n}$.

It is therefore enough to show that $(1+a_n)^{b_n-\frac{c}{a_n}}\rightarrow 0$.

For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|a_nb_n-c|<\varepsilon$. This implies that $|b_n-\frac{c}{a_n}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{a_n}$.

Therefore $(1+a_n)^{b_n-\frac{c}{a_n}} < (1+a_n)^{\frac{\varepsilon}{a_n}}$ and the latter convergence to $e^\varepsilon$. As $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary small, $e^\varepsilon$ is arbitrary close to $1$ and this completes the proof.